# Python to detect latex mathematics using regular expressions or other methods

Tags: python, string-matching

I want to detect if a long text string (input from "somewhere") contains mathematical expressions [encoded in LaTeX](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics). This means searching for substrings (denoted `...` in what follows) enclosed inside either of:

1. `$...$`
2. `\[...\]`
3. `\(...\)`
4. `\begin{displaymath} ... \end{displaymath}`

There are some variations of item 3 with other keywords than `displaymath`, and there may be a whitespace inside the brace, etc., but I suppose I can figure out the rest once I get (1), (2), (3) working.

For (1), I suppose I can do the following:

```
import re
if re.search(r"$(\w+)$", str):
  (do something)`
```

But I am having problems with the others, especially when it has the `\`. Help would be appreciated.

The python version should be 2.7.12 but ideally code that works for both versions 2.x and 3.x will be preferred.

Comment: You need to catch `$$` pairs too and whitespace in braces is syntax error by default. Is this a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182879/regex-to-match-latex-equations  ?

Comment: Oh, did not know that it is syntax error. Yes, the question looks similar. I could not easily find one in search. Thanks. Yes, `$$` pairs need to be caught but they would anyway be caught in the `$...$` search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `\`,`[`,`]`,`{`,`}`,`(`,`)` as they have special meaning in regular expression.

So, you need to add an extra `\` before them, when you want to match them literally.

For your second pattern, use:

```
\\\[(.+?)\\\]
```

For third pattern, use:

```
\\\((.+?)\\\)
```

For fourth pattern,

```
\\begin\{displaymath\}(.+?)\\end\{displaymath\}
```

You can see the demo for the fourth pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/xG8mA8/1).

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Just an addition, you need to add  a '\'  before '$' also, as they mean end of the string in regex. Good luck.